# Language bar in RHEL 6

Tags: rhel, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I'm having a problem with the language bar specifically in RHEL 6.5. I need the following:

1. Language bar on the panel with either 2-letter code or a flag
2. Switch languages with Caps Lock, optionally turn lead on/off on it

By default 1 & 2 are not working. Applying custom settings in `System->Keyboard` does not work. The application [QXKB](https://code.google.com/p/qxkb/) somehow improves bullet #1, but is too unstable to be usable.

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using?

Comment: GNOME Version: 2.28.2

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.

If you want to switch quickly between multiple keyboard layout, you'll see [here](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/3.7/keyboard-layouts.html.en) how to test it and how to add a shortcut to it.

Gnome 2.X documentation is no longer available online, but it should be quite the same.

If you want to switch between language, it's not possible without log out of your session, according to gnome [documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/3.7/session-language.html.en)

Edit: you'll see [here](http://www.ubuntuask.com/q/answers-how-change-gnome-langauge-446169.html) a step-by-step how to add correctly language in language bar, even with a broken gnome installation.

Comment: I wouldn't expect GNOME 2 and GNOME 3 docs to be "quite the same". There was major changes b/w 2 & 3. Also you linked to an Ubuntu method for doing this, I would bet money that that method is NOT applicable to RHEL.

Comment: slm is right. How to make my question clear?  1. I setup language bar behavior on all OS I had (Ubuntu,Centos, RH early editions from RHv7, Mac, Win) except RHEL6, so this problem is specific to this version of RHEL+GNOME. 2. I use QXKB(written on QT)  and it is near to what I want , but it does not keep its settings, I have to setup settings again and again.

Comment: I don't need to change system language